# Load QEMU Firmware Configuration Device in virt-manager?

Tags: qemu, virt-manager

Is there a way to load `fw_cfg file` in `virt-manager` (v1.4.1)?

On the plain `QEMU` command line I can do it like so:

```
-fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=some/file.json
```

I cannot find equivalent option in the `virt-manager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was informed in the [mailing list](https://www.redhat.com/archives/virt-tools-list/2017-June/msg00068.html) that:

> ...this will never be implemented into the virt-manager GUI.

Fortunately there's a workaround, as it's possible to set this via `virt-xml`/`virt-install`.

Eg.: you have created a virtual machine in `virt-manager` *GUI* and named it `VM-1`.

Now you can attach `fw_cfg` file to your virtual machine by using `virt-xml`:

```
virt-xml VM-1 --edit --qemu-commandline="-fw_cfg name=opt/com.coreos/config,file=/full/path/to/file.json"
```

However note, this is just an experimental feature in `libvirt`, more info [here](http://libvirt.org/drvqemu.html#qemucommand).